# Xcode app distribution fails after update of OS and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-distribution

I have such an error in the organizer while distributing my app. The app builds and works ok in Debug mode on simulator or iPhone. It also Archived but I cannot distribute it via Development distribution from organizer!

```
ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec::NonZeroExitException: $ /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/bitcode-build-tool -v -t /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin --sdk /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk -o /var/folders/ls/0vdttqm92zq1rtcsjntc4mxw0000gn/T/ipatool20200210-7826-1kq2c5j/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/CRM\ Dev.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities --generate-dsym /var/folders/ls/0vdttqm92zq1rtcsjntc4mxw0000gn/T/ipatool20200210-7826-1kq2c5j/thinned-out/arm64/Payload/CRM\ Dev.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities.dSYM --strip-swift-symbols /var/folders/ls/0vdttqm92zq1rtcsjntc4mxw0000gn/T/ipatool20200210-7826-1kq2c5j/thinned-in/arm64/Payload/CRM\ Dev.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
Status: pid 8359 exit 2
Stdout:
    SDK path: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.4.sdk
    SDK version: 13.4
```

UPDATE

If I uncheck Rebuild form bitcode then it distributes. But I think it can cause problem later if I want to distribute app to App Store?

Comment: Hello Michał Ziobro, have you found a solution to this problem? If so, would you mind to share that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

need to check the transporter App Apple launches to upload the apps to app Store
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10152019a. It's going to help

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13.4 is a beta version. The app store doesn't accept builds created with beta versions.

Comment: It is not for app store but for firebase distribution of development build

Comment: The same was with iOS 13.2 I tested this archiving both with newest Xcode beta release and with newest Xcode update from App Store.

Answer (score 0):

We've got similar issue, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65077795/ios-macos-app-distribution-failed-while-using-framework-after-upgrading-xcode12). No needs to distribute without bitcode. Long story short, there were LLVM instrumentation included, which prevents AppStore processing. I've written a whole blog about [XCode 12 and BigSur issues with XCFramework](https://blog.scichart.com/xcframework-xcode-12-and-bigsur-issues/).

To sum up, here is a few required steps to make sure while creating `XCFramework` for distribution:

- Using archive builds is a **MUST**, release build isn't enough
- `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` must be set to `YES`
- `SKIP_INSTALL`  must be set to `NO`
- `GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS = NO` to turn off GCC instrumentation and remove them from the binary
- `CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE = NO` to turn off code coverage tools from the binary

Having all of the above helped to solve our preparing and distribution problem and hopefully save you some time if you happened to face same issues as we did.